# How can I create an unit test to an v-alert from Vuetify?

Tags: testing, jestjs, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

## Problem

Jest is returning the whole Vuetify component, and I can't get only the content

## Question

How can I create an unit test to an v-alert from Vuetify?

## My goal

I want to get the content text of the alert and test if this alert text is correct

## Code

### Test

```js
fit('should show error message if username or password are not present', () => {
        const { getByTestId } = renderComponent()
        const alert = getByTestId('alert')
        const loginButton = getByTestId('login-button')
        userEvent.click(loginButton)
    
        // const alert = screen.getByText('Insira seu Login e Senha.')
    
        expect(alert).toBe({})
      })
```

### Results

```js
      - Expected  -  1
    + Received  + 22

    - Object {}
    + <div
    +   class="v-alert v-sheet theme--dark v-alert--dense v-alert--text error--text"
    +   data-testid="alert"
    +   role="alert"
    +   style="display: none;"
    + >
    +   <div
    +     class="v-alert__wrapper"
    +   >
    +     <i
    +       aria-hidden="true"
    +       class="v-icon notranslate v-alert__icon mdi mdi-alert theme--dark error--text"
    +     />
    +     <div
    +       class="v-alert__content"
    +     >
    +       
    +     
    +   
    +     </div>
    +   </div>
    + </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't do this using `testing-library`, I do this using `vue-test-utils` that is more complicated, but work.

## Challenge

If anyone can resolve using `testing-library` please, answer here.

## Solution

```js
it('should show error message if username or password are not present', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Form, {
      localVue,
      vuetify,
    })

    const loginButton = wrapper.find('[data-testid="login-button"]')
    loginButton.trigger('click')
    await Vue.nextTick()

    const alertMessage = wrapper.find('.v-alert__content')

    expect(alertMessage.text()).toBe('Insira seu Login e Senha.')
  })
```